# Double integral objective question.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Let $G(t,x):[0,1]\times [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be defined as

$$
G(t,x)=\begin{cases}
t(1-x)& \text{if $t\leq x\leq 1$ }\\
x(1-t) & \text{if $x\leq t\leq 1$}
\end{cases}
$$ For a continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$ define $$I(f)=\int_0^1\int_0^1G(t,x)f(t)f(x)dtdx$$ Which of the following is true?

$1$. $I(f)>0$ if $f$ is not identically zero.

$2.$ $I(f)=0$ for some non-zero $f$.

$3.$ $I(f)<0$ for some non-zero $f$.

$4$. $I(sin(\pi x))=1.$

It’s single option correct question. How to solve it ? $G(t,x)$ is clearly non negative as given, but value of  $f$ is not given so  value of $f(t)f(x)$ in integrand can be negative? If minimum value of $f$ is positive then I can say that Integral will be positive . One way can be think about this question as the given function $G(t,x)$ is green function corresponding to ODE $$y’’=-f(x), y(0)=y(1)=0$$ Please help . Thank you.

Comment: Note that if (1) is false, then either (2) or (3) has to be true. Thus (4) can be automatically eliminated as a possible true statement. But it might be wise to examine (4) anyway to see if it could demonstrate (2) or (3).

Comment: Unable to understand this one

Comment: If it is false that for all $f \not\equiv 0, I(f) > 0$, then there exists some $f \not\equiv 0$ with $I(f) \le 0$ If $I(f) = 0$, that means (2) is true. If $I(f) < 0$, that means (3) is true. Similarly if every $f \not\equiv 0$ has $I(f) > 0$, then obviously there is no $f$ with $I(f) = 0$ and there is no $f$ with $I(f) < 0$. This is basic logic.